# Xamarin.Forms: How to navigate to TabbedPage's child page

Tags: xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

I meet a scenario to navigate from MyTabbedPage/ChildTabPage1/Page1 to MyTabbedPage/ChildTabPage2/Page2 in Xamarin.Forms

Right now, I can only switch between MyTabbedPage/ChildTabPage1 and MyTabbedPage/ChildTabPage2. But I need to navigate directly from MyTabbedPage/ChildTabPage1/Page1 to MyTabbedPage/ChildTabPage2/Page2

How to achieve this?
Thank you very much in advance for your helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this.

```
public App()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  var parentPage = new MasterDetailView(); // name of the master detail page
  parentPage.IsPresented = false;
  var tabbedPage = new MasterDetailTabbedPage(); // name of the tabbed page
  tabbedPage.CurrentPage = tabbedPage.Children[2]; // specify the index of the tab 
  parentPage.Detail = new NavigationPage(tabbedPage); // assign the tabbed page to master detail page
  MainPage = parentPage; // navigate to master detail page (3rd tab selected)
 }
```

Comment: your solution seems only to navigate from MyTabbedPage/ChildTabPage1 to MyTabbedPage/ChildTabPage2

Comment: var mainTabbedPage = new MainTabbedPage();
            mainTabbedPage.CurrentPage = mainTabbedPage.Children[1];
            mainTabbedPage.CurrentPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new Page2());
            MainPage =new NavigationPage(mainTabbedPage);    you can try this

Comment: it works functionally. but mainTabbedPage.Children[1] is viewed during the navigation. How to make clear navigation?

Comment: For that i need to check

Answer (score 0):

If you want to navigate MyTabbedPage/ChildTabPage1/Page1 to MyTabbedPage/ChildTabPage2/Page2 in Xamarin.Forms, I suggest you can consider to use **Shell** to do this.

**Xamarin.Forms Shell** includes a URI-based navigation experience that uses routes to navigate to any page in the application, without having to follow a set navigation hierarchy. In addition, it also provides the ability to navigate backwards without having to visit all of the pages on the navigation stack.

Here is the article about using Shell:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation

Comment: seems Xamarin.Forms Shell is still in experimental stage, but the features it provided are quite useful. I will definitely try it once it's in stable stage